# Constraint for curriculum to be met with Optapy - School timetabling optimization

Tags: python, optapy

I am using Optapy library in python and I want to add constraint that the curriculum needs to be met, since I get for now many unassigned lessons even though most of the timeslots and rooms are empty and the teacher resources are mostly unused.
I tried to add the following constraint:

```
def curriculum_needs_to_be_met(constraint_factory):
return constraint_factory \
    .forEach(LessonClass) \
    .filter(lambda lesson: lesson.timeslot is None) \
    .penalize("Curriculum needs to be met", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
```

But still I get many unassigned lessons. Any idea how can I define the curriculum constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables should be assigned without a constraint. The only reason why they would be unassigned is either:

1. You are checking the input problem (where all the lessons are unassigned) instead of the solution returned from `solver.solve` (where all the lessons should be assigned, unless the solver terminated before it found a feasible solution (in which case, the solver should be given more time)).
2. You passed `nullable=True` to `@planning_variable` (i.e. the domain looks like this):

   ```
    @planning_entity
    class Lesson:
        def __init__(self, id, subject, teacher, student_group, timeslot=None, room=None):
            self.id = id
            self.subject = subject
            self.teacher = teacher
            self.student_group = student_group
            self.timeslot = timeslot
            self.room = room

        @planning_id
        def get_id(self):
            return self.id

        @planning_variable(Timeslot, ["timeslotRange"], nullable=True)
        def get_timeslot(self):
            return self.timeslot

        def set_timeslot(self, new_timeslot):
            self.timeslot = new_timeslot

        # ...
   ```

   which you do if you want to allow the variable to take a None value. However, this is probably not the case, since you don't want the variable to take a None value.

Thus, I would double check you are using the solution instead of the problem. If you are using the solution and still see unassigned values, then I would update its TerminationConfiguration to give it more time. See the OptaPlanner docs for example termination configurations: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms.html#termination ; You can create a new termination configuration in OptaPy like this:

```
import optapy.config
termination = optapy.config.solver.termination.TerminationConfig()
termination.setBestScoreFeasible(True) # keep solving until the solution feasible
solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig() \
    .withTerminationConfig(termination) \
# rest of SolverConfig setup
```

Comment: It actually worked. I had to set the termination duration as you wrote. I get a feasible solution, but how can I define the target function in addition to the feasible solution that I may get. E.g., I want to minimize the rooms or teachers resources that I use, since I pay a rent or salaries for that, or to minimize the empty hours of rooms/teachers during a day

Comment: The target function are your constraints. In particular, hard constraints define what is feasible, and soft constraints define what you want/don't want in a solution. You could add a soft constraint that counts the number of teachers/rooms used. Generally speaking, the more time given to the solver, the better the solution will be found. It up to you to determine how much time to give the solver. In most cases, it is impractical to find the optimal solution due to the huge search space, so the best solution found in time allotted is used instead.

Comment: I understand. If the algorithm find two feasible solution with the same amount of broken soft constraints (i.e. 5 soft constrains broken), which one will be chosen? Is it possible to define a criterion for that? Do you know how can I count the numbers of rooms/teachersin every solution that the algorithm examine and add constraints that penalize the number of rooms/teachers?

Comment: It not based on the number of broken constraints, but the score of the solution. For instance, in VRP, the length of the route is penalized, but (typically) there is only one constraint "broken" per route. To count "rooms/teachers", I would do something like `constraint_factory.forEach(LessonClass).groupBy(lambda lesson: lesson.teacher).penalize("Minimize used teachers", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT)` (change the lambda in groupBy to do similarly for room); this constraint reads "for each teacher referenced by at least one Lesson, penalize by one soft".

Comment: If two solutions have the same score, the first one OptaPlanner found will be used (the best solution changes only when a new solution with a better score is found).

Comment: I understand. Is there another way to write the constraint that penalize the number of teachers? I mean, how can I sum the number of hours for each teacher and penalize if it positive number? I am asking that since it relates to another constraint which I want to implement to penalize the if hours limit of teacher is exceeded. So far, the constraint examples  usually penalized 2 lessons. But how to penalize amount (of hours)?

Comment: The `penalize` method can optionally take a function that maps the penalized tuple to a positive integer, which will be multiplied with the base score passed to `penalized`. For instance, `penalize("Lesson length", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, lambda lesson: lesson.length)` will penalize by 8 soft if `lesson.length` is 8 hours. To sum the number of hours for each teacher, use `groupBy(lambda lesson, teacher: teacher, ConstraintCollectors.sum(ToIntBiFunction @ (lambda lesson, teacher: lesson.length)))`. The ToIntBiFunction is from `java.util.function`, which need to be imported.

Comment: I defined it in the as follows: `def teacher_limit(constraint_factory): return constraint_factory \  .forEach(LessonClass) \ .groupBy(lambda lesson, teacher: teacher, ConstraintCollectors.sum(ToIntBiFunction @ (lambda lesson, teacher: lesson.length))) \ .penalize("Teacher hours", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT)` . How can I define the constraint if I want to penalize if a defined threshold is met? (e.g. penalize if teacher is working more than 8 hours). In addition, when I use the constraint I get the error: name 'ConstraintCollectors' is not defined. Any help?

Comment: `ConstraintsCollectors` need to be imported: `from optapy.constraint import ConstraintsCollectors`. To add a threshold, add a filter: `def teacher_limit(constraint_factory): return constraint_factory \  .forEach(LessonClass) \ .groupBy(lambda lesson, teacher: teacher, ConstraintCollectors.sum(ToIntBiFunction @ (lambda lesson, teacher: lesson.length))) \ .filter(lambda teacher, hours: hours > 8) \ .penalize("Teacher hours", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT)`

Comment: How is `hours`defined? I mean, how the `lesson.length` amount is routed to the variable `hours`?

Comment: It appears there is a missing `join` that joins the teacher (unless teacher is on lesson, then the groupBy first parameter should change to `lambda lesson: lesson.teacher`). `hours` is defined as the sum of all lesson.length that have the same teacher (it is the result of ConstraintCollector.sum).